# Создание интерактивной карты местности

Tags: ios, swift, canvas, svg, карты

Всем привет! Я хочу сделать интерактивную карту своего района на платформе ios в качестве дипломного проекта. Фактически это как 2gis, только местность ограниченная, ну и из функционала необходимо только просмотр карты и информации о зданиях.
У меня возникло ряд вопросов:

1. Карта должна быть красивой, с не просто из гугла. Поэтому вопрос: в каком формате эту карту нужно нарисовать? в SVG? Легко ли будет работать с SVG на ios, в плане по перемещению по нему и выделению областей домов по определённой позиции. Или может быть мне необходимо стилизировать google maps каким-то образом?
2. Как можно синхронизировать этот SVG с долготой и широтой так, чтобы можно было определять местоположение текущее?
3. Может быть есть какие-то готовые решения, заготовки или обучающий материал?

Comment: Хочу сделать дипломный проект более красивым, чем карты Google. Очень смешно. Готовых решений - пруд пруди.

Comment: карты Google тут не причём. Карта района должна выглядеть более детально, чтобы человек понимал что это за здание, а не просто схема. Так вот я и прошу указать мне на готовые решения, фреймворки.

Comment: Как же ни при чем: "Карта должна быть красивой, с не просто из гугла"

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать действительно серьезный проект, с привязкой к реальным координатам, вам стоит изучить [создание собственных наложений на карту Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays?hl=ru), а также [стилизацию карт Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=ru).

Comment: ого, спасибо. Буду изучать. А ещё я наткнулся на openstreetmaps. Там прям можно необходимый район выделить, скачать в формате osm - и как угодно его потом редактировать. Не знаете ничего про это? Потому что может быть будет проще и эффективнее не просто накладывать картинку на карту, а заменять текстуры определённых объектов карты (дороги, магазины, дома)

Comment: Про osm ничего не могу сказать. А насчет проще и эффективнее - вопрос спорный. В гуглокартах все не так сложно, на самом деле. И мастер стилей есть: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: Я в гугл картах так и не нашёл способ вырезать лишь часть карты. Чтобы грузилось и показывалось только карта района, а не всего мира. А в osm прям выделяешь область и выгружаешь. Но в osm действительно большие сложности. Вы не знаете, можно ли в google картах брать кусок определённый?

Comment: Точно не скажу. Но и проблемы не вижу. Выводите на экран кусок карты в нужном масштабе, и все. Можно даже масштабирование запретить и протяжку карты. Все можно.

Comment: Подробно как вырезать кусок OpenStreetMap и использовать для OfflineMap под IOS с помощью библиотеки Route-me.
http://shiki.me/blog/offline-maps-in-ios-using-openstreetmap-and-route-me
Редакторов OpenStreetMap много, например, JOSM.